# Mongo mock коллекция

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mock

Пытаюсь "замокать" `MongoDB`. В интернетах нашел что надо мокать `MongoCursor` (из пространства имен `MongoDB.Driver`) - его нет, или он не торчит.

Вот такое вот пока написано :

```
var collection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<UiCustomizationData>>();

collection.Setup(mongoCollection => temp);


var database = new Mock<IMongoDatabase>();

database.Setup(x =>
  x.GetCollection<UiCustomizationData>("UiCustomizationData", new MongoCollectionSettings()))
   .Returns(collection.Object);

var repo = new UiCustomizationRepository(new UiCustomizationDataContext(database.Object));
```

Мокаю свою базу, и хочу в коллекцию подложить свою.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По логике вещей нужно мокать `IMongoCursor<T>`, например:

```
var collection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<UiCustomizationData>>();
var cursorMock = new Mock<IMongoCursor<UiCustomizationData>>();

сursorMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(temp.GetEnumerator());
```

и потом:

```
collection.Setup(m => /*Ваш запрос*/).Returns(cursorMock.Object);
```

---

В новых версия нужно мокать `IAsyncCursor<T>`, пробовал так (полный код):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Moq;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var temp = new List<UiCustomizationData>
      {
        new UiCustomizationData { Name = "1" },
        new UiCustomizationData { Name = "2" }
      };

      var coll = new Mock<IMongoCollection<UiCustomizationData>>();

      var cursorMock = new Mock<IAsyncCursor<UiCustomizationData>>();
      cursorMock.Setup(x => x.Current).Returns(temp);

      coll
        .Setup(x => x.FindAsync(It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<UiCustomizationData>>(), It.IsAny<FindOptions<UiCustomizationData>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(() => cursorMock.Object);

      var r = coll.Object.FindAsync(x => x.Id == 1).Result;

      foreach (var item in r.Current)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
      }
    }
  }

  public class UiCustomizationData
  {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
  }
}
```

Comment: у меня нет возможности мокать 'IMongoCursor', возможно потому что я делаю это все под .core

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, похоже что способ подмены курсора уже не актуальный, курсор перенесли в пакет - MongoDB.Driver.Legacy

Comment: @ParanoidPanda обновил ответ)